# Go to given url after checking condition

Tags: javascript, html

Arter clicking i need to run `chkMethode()` in javaScript and then I decide is it go to the url or not

When i clicked 'Go' it does not run chkMethode() directly go to the given link.  what to do?

```
     <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="chkMethode()"> Go </a>
```

Comment: Are you sure your page is loading your javascript correctly? Can you post on your code for chkmethode() on here?

Comment: You shouldn't use inline event handlers, prefer using external event listeners instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's because JavaScript needs to prevent the anchor from performing its usual event and it does this using `preventDefault`. Here, as best practice, I've separated out your JS from the HTML and used an `id`.

HTML

```
<a id="go" href="http://www.google.com">Go</a>
```

JS

```
var go = document.getElementById('go');
go.onclick = chkMethode;

function chkMethode(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (check) {
    window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks more straightforward and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
function chkMethode(event)
{
  if (<<certain condition>>)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}

<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return chkMethode(event)"> Go </a>
```

Comment: You're better off with `preventDefault` as the first statement. It's unlikely the check will be made if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function chkMethode () {
    Var valuetochck = // value to be checked
    If(valuetochck == "")
    {
        Window.location.href="url1";
    }
    Else
    {
        Window.location.href="url2";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question why the the browser goes directly to the link without running the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault();chkMethode();" href="http://www.google.com" > Go </a>
```